# Looking for a technique to reduce "controller repetition" for CRUD operation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am developing the administration part of a site. It mostly consist of manipulating list of data such as:

- Products
- Suppliers
- Tax profiles
- ...

I find the task of creating a controller that handle the CRUD operations of each model a little too repeating and prone to mistake from one controller to another.

I would still need to adapt some of these controller for additional operation, but not all.

Does someone know a proven approach for reducing the implication of controller for the usual CRUD operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion would be to look at tweaking the T4 template that is used to generate the scaffold methods.  Check out Rob Conery's [MVC Starter Site](http://mvcstarter.codeplex.com) to see what he's done (look in `/Web/CodeTemplates` in the source for the general idea).

There are also some other MVC libraries out there such as [FubuMVC](http://www.fubumvc.com) that aim to cut down on code repetition, but it's not based on the actual ASP.NET MVC framework (and it's not really my thing).